# For loop not recognizing special characters inside an array as single chars

Tags: c, arrays

The below code is not finding '/n' and replacing with '/0'. Looks like the compiler thinks '/n' and '/0' are more than single characters and are expecting integer values. I have tried atoi(), however this did not work.

Thanks in advance.

```
for (i=0; i<sizeof(filename); i++){
    if (filename[i] == ('/n')) {
        filename[i]= ('/0');
        break;
    }
}

createbn.c:35:21: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
                                    ^
createbn.c:35:21: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing
  'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
```

On a modern mac, gcc compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to use a backward slash to represent the special characters:

```
\0
\n
```

The forward slash does not make it a escape sequence, `/0` are two characters.

Comment: Love you (7 more characters)